# How to use Trail Renderer in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity3d I have a movable object that I want to trace it . according to my search there is a function called Trail Renderer I don't know how to use it in script any one can provide me with how can I use it in clear way

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a function, [it's a script](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-TrailRenderer.html).

Real easy to use, just select a game object and go to **Menu->Component->Effects->Trail Renderer**.  Just follow the documentation page for filling in the material properties.  All of the trail renderer properties are exposed to the Unity editor's inspector so you can play with start and end widths, material props., etc w/o having to write additional code.